# How can I increase and decrease the quantity of only one items in the cart using provider in flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

This is a code that will be displayed on each item in the cart list. Whereby the user will have an option of increase and decreasing the number of quantity of each desired item. I have tried using Consumer widget and some other tricks but when I click the add Icon the number of quantity increases to the entire list of cart items.

```
Container(
  child: Row(children: [
     IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
        onPressed: () {
           setState(() {
              _itemCount--;
              });
           }),
        Text(_itemCount.toString()),
           IconButton(
             icon: Icon(Icons.add),
             onPressed: () {
             setState(() {
             _itemCount++;
                });
            })
     ]))
```

This is my change notifier class.

```
class ItemQuantity with ChangeNotifier {
  int _numberOfItems = 0;

  int get numberOfItems => _numberOfItems;

  display(int no) async {
_numberOfItems = no;

   notifyListeners();
 }
 }
```

I want to achieve the following.

1. Increase or decrease the quantity of individual items.
2. Increase or decrease the total amount payable.
   [image]

```
 Future saveUserInfoToFireStore(User fUser) async {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(fUser.uid).set({
    "uid": fUser.uid,
    "email": fUser.email,
    "name": _nameTextEditingController.text.trim(),
    "url": userImageUrl,
    EcommerceApp.userCartList: [
      "garbageValue"
     ],
});

await EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences
    .setStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList, ["garbageValue"]);
```

}

Comment: You should provide `id` to your cart list, right now it'll effect whole cart item

Comment: In that case my id will be var itemID = model.itemID; How so I proceed from there??

Comment: while you display the data for each cartItem that dataModel should have itemCount respective to eachItem. If you could show your provider code for the cartUi may be I can give more precise answer

Comment: Well, I have restricted the user from adding items that already exist in the cartList so there is no way they can add more than one similar item. Just to show you how I have saved the cartList item for each user. I have edited my question and added the that specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your data is coming from a model class.

Example:

```
class ProductModel{
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final int price;
  final String img;
  late int qty;

  ProductModel({required this.id,required this.name, required this.price, required this.img, required this.qty});

  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return ProductModel(
      id: json['productID'],
      name: json['name'], 
      price: json['price'],
      img: json['img'],
      qty: json['qty'],
      );
  }
}
```

On you UI page you are returning a ListView and each item is getting displayed on its index.
For example, here is the list where you are storing you data.

```
List<ProductModel> data = state.mydata;

return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index){
                return Card(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 80,
                          child: Image(image: NetworkImage(data[index].img)),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(data[index].name),
                              Text('Price: ${data[index].price.toString()} Rs'),
// to set the quantity
                              Row(
                                children:  [
                                  InkWell(
                                    onTap : (){
                                      setState(() {
                                        data[index].qty --;
                                      });
                                    },
                                      child: data[index].qty >= 1 ? const Icon(Icons.remove_circle) : Container(child: Text('No'),)
                                  ),
                                  Text(data[index].qty.toString()),

                                  InkWell(
                                    onTap: (){
                                      setState(() {
                                        data[index].qty ++;
                                      });
                                    },
                                      child: const Icon(Icons.add_circle)),
                                ],
                              ), 
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),

                        ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                          _postData(context);
                        }, child: const Text('Add to cart')),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              );
```

by using this

```
setState(() {
    data[index].qty ++;
});
```

it will only update the value on specific index...

[image]